# Multiple Mysqli Select Statement, echo separated results

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I have looked online for a solution to my problem for many hours to no avail.

I have multiple selct statements, receiving data from different mysql tables.
I want to echo completely separated results. Currently, results are printed as if they are one,
so I cannot work on the answers separately.

Suppose the output from table is:

```
100
200
300
400
```

I want to echo out:

```
result1 = 100;
result2 = 200;
```

etc

So I can work on the final results in another program. If a result is null, it should not produce an error,
but just post 0.
Example, if output from mysql table is:

```
100
null
null
100
```

I want the output to clearly show

```
result1 = 100;
result2 = 0;
result3 = 0;
result4 = 100;
```

etc.

```
$check_sco = 100;

$sql = "SELECT TABLE_1 FROM RIDER_1 WHERE score1=$check_sco;";
$sql .= "SELECT TABLE_1 FROM RIDER_2 WHERE score1=$check_sco;";
$sql .= "SELECT TABLE_1 FROM RIDER_3 WHERE score1=$check_sco;";
$sql .= "SELECT TABLE_1 FROM RIDER_4 WHERE score1=$check_sco";


if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);//how to echo separated result that can be manipulated indepedently?
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

} while (mysqli_next_result($con));
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just run them in sequence?

```
$check_sco = 100;

$riders = array();
for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
    $sql = "SELECT TABLE_1 FROM RIDER_" . $i . " WHERE score1=" . $check_sco;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $riders[] = ($row['TABLE_1']) ? $row['TABLE_1'] : 0;
}
```

Then you'll have an array with the results you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) which if TABLE_1 is not null it will return TABLE_1 otherwise it will give you 0

```
SELECT IFNULL(TABLE_1, 0) FROM RIDER_1 WHERE score1=$check_sco;
SELECT IFNULL(TABLE_1, 0) FROM RIDER_2 WHERE score1=$check_sco;
SELECT IFNULL(TABLE_1, 0) FROM RIDER_3 WHERE score1=$check_sco;
SELECT IFNULL(TABLE_1, 0) FROM RIDER_4 WHERE score1=$check_sco
```